# React-Native: Update Screen With Custom-Component-Loop Via Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

There are multiple screens in a `StackNavigator`. The `TopScreen` pushes another screen on the stack. The second screen then calls an event in `TopScreen` and closes itself / goes back to `TopScreen`. The data within `TopScreen` should now reflect the changes that have been made to it; The screen should be redrawn. How can / should this be archived?

```
// Screen in NavigatorStack
function TopScreen(props) {
  // Custom Data
  const [entries, setEntries] = React.useState(props.route.params.entries);

  // Event emitted by another screen that will return to this screen
  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("event.refreshEntries", (eventData) =>
  {
    let newEntries = entries;
    newEntries[0].text = "foo"; // TEST
    setEntries(newEntries);
  });
  
  React.useEffect(() => { // Should somehow refresh screen?
      // ?
    }), [entries];

  return ( // Does not refresh
    <View>
      {/* Custom Component */}
      {entries.map(entry => (
        <EntryCustomComponent key={entry.id} {...entry} />
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}
```